# Matching data with duplicates for self-update with different sources in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have a set of data with duplicates:

```
x <- tibble(num=c(1,2,3,2,5,5,8), alph=NA)
```

And separate sources giving their corresponding values.

```
y <- tibble(num=1:4, alph=LETTERS[1:4])
z <- tibble(num=5:10, alph=LETTERS[5:10])
```

Normally, one would use this code to update `x$num` with data from `y`.

```
x$alph <- y$alph[match(x$num,y$num)]
```

Doing the same for `z` would nonetheless overwrite what was already in place from `y` and replace them with `NA`s.

How can I code so that data can be cumulatively updated? Using:

```
x$alph[which(x$num %in% z$num)] <- y$alph[which(z$num %in% x$num)]
```

doesn't work because of the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Here I provided three options using `tidyverse`. `x2`, `x4`, and `x5` are the final output.

We can create a combined data frames from `y` and `z`, and then perform a join with `x`.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data frames
x <- tibble(num=c(1,2,3,2,5,5,8), alph=NA)
y <- tibble(num=1:4, alph=LETTERS[1:4])
z <- tibble(num=5:10, alph=LETTERS[5:10])

# Create combined table from y and z
yz <- bind_rows(y, z)

# Perform join
x2 <- x %>% 
  select(-alph) %>%
  left_join(yz, by = "num")
x2
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#     num  alph
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     A
# 2     2     B
# 3     3     C
# 4     2     B
# 5     5     E
# 6     5     E
# 7     8     H
```

Or use `reduce` to merge all data frames, then select the one that is not `NA` to construct a new data frame.

```
x3 <- reduce(list(x, y, z), left_join, by = "num")
x4 <- tibble(num = x3$num,
             alph = apply(x3[, -1], 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]))
x4
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#     num  alph
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     A
# 2     2     B
# 3     3     C
# 4     2     B
# 5     5     E
# 6     5     E
# 7     8     H
```

Or after the `reduce` and `join`, Use `gather` to remove `NA` values.

```
x3 <- reduce(list(x, y, z), left_join, by = "num")
x5 <- x3 %>% 
  gather(Type, alph, -num, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select(-Type)
x5
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#     num  alph
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     A
# 2     2     B
# 3     3     C
# 4     2     B
# 5     5     E
# 6     5     E
# 7     8     H
```